# Problem with the Documents module. Odoo 15

Tags: odoo

My inquiry is about the issue I have when creating a document in Odoo. I can only create the document as a superuser; any other user receives a permission denied message, and it asks for the corresponding permissions. Even if I grant them the permissions, it still doesn't work. Is there anyone who knows how I can allow any user to create documents when they register?

How do I solve the problem?